# How to move to particular child element in a linearlayout which is a single element of listview in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview with one element only.
but the element contains about 20 inner childs. if i select any of inner child and back to list then the list view is scrolling to up, and i have to scroll down to see the selected items.

I have tried with smoothScroll method but it works only if list elements are more not for this single element.

can any one please help me how to scroll the listview to selected child element

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Umm, why do you have a listView with only 1 element?  If all you want is listView's scrolling, use ScrollView instead.  Bonus- it's easier to scroll.

Comment: I am working on DrawerLayout which allows frameLayout and Listview. it will not allow the scrollview so that i continue with the listview with single element and its child elements.

Comment: Why not a FrameLayout with a ScrollView in it?